# Como consigo para timers que fora iniciados por uma task c#

Tags: c#, thread, timer, task

Olá, estou tentando entender uma situação mas até então não consegui resolvê-la. Imagina que temos uma classe X que tem um timer que é iniciado pelo construtor. Agora imagina que esta mesma classe é instanciada dentro de uma thread.

Fazendo alguns testes no meu código percebi que se eu der dispose na thread, o timer que está rodando na classe vai continuar rodando. Já tentei criar uma lista e tentar parar o timer dos objetos mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Um exemplo do problema em uma solução de console c# -

```
public class Phone
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        private int ID;

        public Phone(int ID)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Dispose();
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Radio ID : " + ID);
            Console.Write(" Launch thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Task> list = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Phone A = new Phone(i);


                list.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

                    A.Start();

                }));


            }

            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(" STOPPING THREAD");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                list[i].Dispose();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você instanciou o objeto dentro da thread principal, e não na thread que você está dando dispose... você só criou outra thread pra chamar o start... enfin...

nessa situação você poderia colocar sua classe Phone para implementar a interface IDisposable e então implementar o método Dispose da sua classe, além de que, se o Phone deve trabalhar assíncrono, você pode colocar a Task dentro dele, o que evita a implementação externa além de evitar o timer. Fiz um código de exemplo:

> Class Phone

```
public class Phone : IDisposable
{
    private int ID;
    private Task t;
    private bool running = false;
    public Phone(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        running = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Radio Start : " + ID);
         t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (running)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Radio ID: {0} Running in Thread {1}", ID, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (running)
        {
            running = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Radio Stopping : " + ID);
            while (t.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parando thread...: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Radio Stopped : " + ID);
            t.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Radio not Running : " + ID);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Radio Disposed : " + ID);
    }
}
```

> Execução:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Phone obj = new Phone(i);
            phones.Add(obj);
            obj.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("STOPPING THREAD");

        foreach (Phone p in phones)
        {
            p.Dispose();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All Threads stopped");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```